# Pyspark access data in folder XXX/2021/12/20

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-synapse, gettime

I have a pipeline running in Azure Synpase and I need to execute a pyspark code that create  a current date folder. The structure must be "2021/12/10" (this is the lastest data that my pipeline was executed.. one folder for year, month and day).

path= 'dataupdated/yyyy/MM/dd' .. i just need to automate the creation of these folders

I think i have to use "get datetime"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **os** library to do that.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime as dt
filename = f"{dt.now().strftime('%Y')}/{dt.now().strftime('%m')}/{dt.now().strftime('%d')}/file.extension" 
#This makedirs below will create directories if not found
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename), exist_ok=True)
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write("test")
```

Answer (score 1):

Creation of folder with the folder structure as : **yyyy/MM/dd** is not possible in **ADLS** as it doesn't accept forward slash as the folder name. Please check the below image.

[image]

Instead you can use the below code to create folder with format: **yyyy-MM-dd**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from datetime import datetime
var=datetime.utcnow()
mssparkutils.fs.mkdirs("/dataupdated/"+var.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

If we try to create folder using

```
mssparkutils.fs.mkdirs("/dataupdated/"+var.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
```

It will treat the next string after forward slash as subfolder.